# How to get friends of users not using my app (Graph 2.4)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends, facebook-invite, facebook-invite-friends

as there were recent changes in Facebook APIs, rights and endpoints, I would like to open this question once again as I spent almost 2 hours by searching for answer without reasonable answer.

My app (web-based-only at now) is based on contact/friends matchmaking. Thats not an issue at all.

In one part of app they can see all friends using the app, thats fine.

Trouble is, that I need my users to be able to invite them friends, which are not using app.

And here we go:

- Send Dialog: Ugly, not intuitive at all, user have to fill in chips
  with names.
- invitable_friends: cut out for my purposes
- tagable_friends: can be used until facebook will found that I am
  using it different way that I should - I don't like this approach

Goal:

- Having a list of friends I can invite into app

Any ideas here in 2017?

Comment: There is no way to get a full friend list expect the two endpoints that are not applicable here. So using the dialogs is the remaining option you got. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_1291953124230220

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a privacy issue to not give access to non-app users to an app. I wouldn't want any app any of my friends are using to know about me or have access to any of my information. Then I would be hit with tons of spam invites for sure. Sorry, but I don't think you'll be able to accomplish what you need right now.

Comment: In fact, I did it before, it was possible and it was changed in November 2016. That a reason why I even asked this question, because this question is answered here, but in old way.
Ad privacy - app is asking for specific permission. Thats the way how its worked before. App told you, that if you want to continue, app will see your friend list. And you can approve it or leave the app. But thats history :/